# Get a specific string form a list of strings that mathces a tricky criteria

Tags: c#, .net, string, linq

I have an object that has a list of strings where each string represents a territory (NUTS codes).
ex.

```
["SE","SE12","SE124"]
```

what I'm trying to do is to get the most general and the most specific one (I don't know If I made sense) I'll write some input examples and what the expected output to be so it gets clearer about what I mean.

```
input1 : ["SE", "SE123", "SE124", "SE123456", "SE123456789"],
input2 : ["SE", "SE2", "SE123", "SE123456", "SE123456789"],
input3 : ["SE", "SE123", "SE123456", "SE123456789"],
input4 : ["SE","FI", "SE2"]
```

the expected output should be : output1 =>"SE12" , output2 => "SE", ouptut3 => "SE123456789", output => "".

I used different approaches but it seems to be trickier than I thought.

my method currently looks like this:

```
 public static string GetSpecificNuts(IList<string> nuts)
{
    var outNuts = "";
    var annNuts = nuts.Distinct().ToList();
    if (annNuts.Any())
    {
        if (annNuts.Count() == 1)
        {
            outNuts = annNuts.SingleOrDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            var grouped = annNuts.GroupBy(n => n.Length).OrderByDescending(n=>n.Key).ToList();
            var highest = grouped.Select(g => g.Key).FirstOrDefault();

            var highestGroup = grouped?.SingleOrDefault(g => g.Key == highest)?.ToList();
            var length = highestGroup?.Count;

            if (length == 1)
            {
                var highestNuts = highestGroup?.SingleOrDefault();
                var contained = grouped?.Where(n => n.Key != highest).SelectMany(g => g.ToList()).Where(s => highestNuts.StartsWith(s)).OrderByDescending(s=>s.Length);
                var firstContained = contained.FirstOrDefault();
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstContained))
                {
                    outNuts = firstContained;
                }
            }
            while (length > 1)
            {
                var deducted = new List<string>();
                highestGroup?.ForEach(i => { deducted.Add(i.Length > 2 ? i.Remove(i.Length - 1, 1) : i); });
                var distinct = deducted?.Distinct().ToList();
                length = distinct?.Count;
                highestGroup = distinct;
                if (length == 1)
                {
                    outNuts = distinct?.SingleOrDefault();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return outNuts;
}
```

any thoughts?

EDIT FOR MORE EXPLANATION:
consider the numbers after the first 2 letters as a tree view. first number represents a group of states, 2nd represents a state, 3rd represents a district and the 4th represents municipalities ..and so on.
I need to get the most specific area and I Achieved that at input3.
but if the list has ex. 2 or more different districts then I need to get the number that represent the state. 2 more different states then I need to get the number that represents the group of states. 2 or more different groups of states then I need to get the first 2 letters that represent the country. 2 or country codes ex ("SE","FI") then the output should be an empty string.

Comment: what are the criteria for expected output? Can you provide that in English

Comment: I added more explanation to the question I hope it will make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clarify what I believe you're looking for: you want to find the NUTS code that represents the most specific division that is either **common for all in the list** or the division for which **all other NUTS codes is a more general division of**. Essentially, find the deepest node in a k-ary tree for which the paths to all leaf nodes pass through:

```
 SE
  \
   5
    \
     7 <-- Most specific in the common branch (SE57)
    / \
   4   2
```

```
 SE
  \
   5 
    \
     7
      \
       2 <-- Most specific in the common branch (SE572)
```

One solution for this could be as follows (giving the method a good name is a little tricky):

```cs
public static string GetDeepestNodeInCommonBranch(IList<string> nutsCodes)
{
    // Build a tree with the depth being the specificity (index in the code) of
    // the country subdivisions and the nodes at each level being the different
    // divisions at that level/specificity (different numbers at the same index).
    
    var levels = nutsCodes.Distinct(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        .SelectMany(nc => nc.Select((c, i) => new {Character = c, Index = i}))
        .GroupBy(obj => obj.Index)
        // Walk the tree from the top
        .OrderBy(g => g.Key);
    
    var commonDiv = string.Empty;
    foreach (var level in levels)
    {
        var divisions = level.Select(obj => obj.Character).Distinct().ToList();
        // If the tree branches out here, the division at the last level is the
        // most specific division common for all
        if (divisions.Count > 1)
        {
            // Only return full country codes
            return commonDiv.Length >= 2 ? commonDiv : string.Empty;
        }
        commonDiv += divisions.Single();
    }
    return commonDiv;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what i'm looking for! Thanks mate you made me feel like this : https://twitter.com/vishalmalvi_/status/1546493087299428352